# form validation not working along with form action

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

I have a registration form which SHOULD check the inputting data according to each function i have created(inside validation.js file) and after everything is ok then it should return all the data to the .php file which will save inthe phpmyadmin database.

However it is not working

Test1: validation is working (alone not included the action=.php)
Test2: without validation the data is storing in the database(phpmyadmin)
Test3: with validation and with action=.php) its not working the validation part

Please help me.

```js
function formValidation()
{
 var id = document.registration.nic;
 var registerno = document.registration.regno;
 var name = document.registration.pname;
 var paddress = document.registration.address;
    var maritial = document.registration.mars;
    var religion = document.registration.rel;
 var addname = document.registration.fhn;
    var pcity = document.registration.city;
 var telephone = document.registration.tel;
 var age = document.registration.ag;
    var gender = document.registration.gen;
    
 
 
  
  
 if(ValidateNIC(id)) //done
  {
  if(allLettername(name)) //done
   {
   
    
     if(allnumericreg(registerno))
     {
     if(alphanumericpaddress(paddress)) //done
      {
      if(maritialselect(maritial)) //done
       {
       if(religionselect(religion)) //done
        {
         
         
         if(allLetteraddname(addname)) //done
          {
          if(alphanumericpcity(pcity)) //done
           {
           if(allnumerictel(telephone)) //done
            {
            if(allnumericage(age)) //done
             {
             if(genderselect(gender)) //done
              {
               
              }
             }
            }
           }
             }
         
        } 
       } 
      }
     }
     
     
   }
  }
  return false;
}




function allLettername(name)
{
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
    if(name.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Patient Name must have alphabet characters only');
        return false;
    }
}

function allLetteraddname(addname)
{
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
    if(addname.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Father or Husband"s Name must have alphabet characters only');
        return false;
    }
}

function maritialselect(maritial)
{
    if(maritial.value == "Default")
    {
        alert("Select your Maritial Status from the list");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

 function ValidateNIC(id)
  {
      var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/;

    if ((id.value.length == 10) && id.value.match(letters))
  {
  return true;
  }
 else
  {
  alert("NIC must contain alphanumeric characters only and must be 10 charators long!");
  id.focus();
  return false;
  }
   }
  

function alphanumericpaddress(paddress)
{
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(paddress.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Patient address must have alphanumeric characters only');
        paddress.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function alphanumericpcity(pcity)
{
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(pcity.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('User City must have alphanumeric characters only');
        pcity.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function religionselect(religion)
{
    if(religion.value == "Default")
    {
        alert("Select your Religion from the list");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function allnumericreg(registerno)
{
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(registerno.value.match(numbers))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Register No Must have numeric characters only");
        return false;
    }
}

function allnumerictel(telephone)
{
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if((telephone.value.length == 10) && telephone.value.match(numbers))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Telephone Number must have numeric characters only and Length should 10 charators long! ");
        return false;
    }
}

function allnumericage(age)
{
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(age.value.match(numbers))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Age must have numeric characters only");
        return false;
    }
}

function genderselect(gender)
{
    if(gender.value == "Default")
    {
        alert("Select your Gender from the list");
        return false;
    }
    
    else
    {
        alert('Registration Form Successfully Submitted');
        window.location.reload()
        return true;
 }
}
```

```css
<?php
$con= mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","hmsjason");
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
echo"Failed to Connect";
}
$sql="INSERT INTO patient(P_NIC,Reg_No,Full_Name,Address,Maritial_Sts,Religion,DOB,H_F_Name,City,Contact,Age,Gender,Room_No)VALUES('$_POST[nic]','$_POST[regno]','$_POST[pname]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[mars]','$_POST[rel]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[fhn]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[tel]','$_POST[ag]','$_POST[gen]','$_POST[room]')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
die("Error".mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
header("location:reception.html");


?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<script src="regvalidation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>

<table background="Images/formbg1.jpg" border="2" align="center" width ="825" height="820" >

<th align=center valign=center>

<form action="patientdetails.php" method="POST"/>
<!--form name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation()"/>-->
<div class="textcenter1">
 <h2>Patient Registration Form</h2>
</div>
<br><br>
<table border="0"; align="center" width ="655" height="550" >
<tr>
<td>
NATIONAL ID :</td><td><input type="text" name="nic" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b>
REGISTRATION NUMBER :</td><td><input type="text" name="regno" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
PATIENT NAME :</td><td><input type="text" name="pname" size="40" />
</td>
<tr>
<td>
PATIENT ADDRESS :</td><td><input type="text" name="address" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Maritial Status: :</td>
   <td>
   <select name="mars">
                <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select your Status)</option>
                <option value="Maried">Married</option>
                <option value="Unmarried">UnMarried</option>
            </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
RELIGION :</td>
   <td>
   <select name="rel">
                <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select your Religion)</option>
                <option value="Buddhist">Buddhist</option>
                <option value="Catholic">Catholic</option>
                <option value="Christian">Christian</option>
                <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
                <option value="Muslim">Muslim</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
            </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Date of Birth: </td><td><input type="date" name="dob">
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
FATHER'S NAME/HUSBAND'S NAME :</td><td><input type="text" name="fhn" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
CITY :</td><td><input type="text" name="city" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
TELEPHONE NUMBER/MOBILE NUMBER :</td><td><input type="text" name="tel" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
AGE :</td><td><input type="text" name="ag" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Gender :</td>
   <td>
   <select name="gen">
                <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select your Gender)</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Room: </td><td><input type="text" name="room">
<td>
</tr>
</b>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input align="left" type="image" src="Images/submit.png" alt="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit" width="115" height="57"/>
</form> 
 <!--if submit button and reset button in same <form> will perform the formvalidation which leds the reset buttton also work as a submit button(wont reset anyting)-->
<form><input align="center" type="image" src="Images/reset.png" alt="Reset" name="reset" value="reset" width="115" height="57"/>


</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>


</th>
</table>
<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think there is something wrong in form inside the HTML file

Comment: It does nothing in `if(genderselect(gender))`. Plus those nested `if` just horrible, there tons of ways to make code more maintainable.

Comment: gender select is a drop down list in html, once selected the value will check(it cannot be default, after everything validate data should store into the database

Answer (score 0):

It appears your validation method always returns false. If the code called by onSubmit returns false, the action will not be executed. The same is true for onclick and other event functions.

Once you've evaluated all the conditions to be valid, you should return true to tell the form that it can take over and do its thing.

Comment: validation part is working, but without form, once i add form it dosent work